# OnClick doesn't work when referring to other styled component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have this styled-component:

```
export const CloseIcon = styled(Config.ICONS.X)`
  position: absolute;
  right: 13px;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  ${Container}:not(:focus-within) & {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
`
```

And this react code:

```
<Container>
  <IconContainer>
    <SearchIcon />
  </IconContainer>
  <Input onChange={handleInputChange} placeholder={placeholder} value={valueOfInput}/>
  <CloseIcon onClick={() => {setValueOfInput('');setSearchValue('');}}/>
</Container>
```

CodeSandBox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-pine-qjxj0

What happens when input has focus:
[image]

What happens if I click the "X" (CloseIcon)
[image]

So, if I click on the CloseIcon the focus is removed from the input, and therefore the CloseIcon gets invisible. However, that "OnClick" inside The CloseIcon, never executes, I tried putting console.logs inside and they never get printed. I also tried making CloseIcon a div instead of a SVGComponent from my config, but the onClick still doesn't work.

What does work tho, is if I put a wrapper around it:

```
<Container>
  <IconContainer>
    <SearchIcon />
  </IconContainer>
  <Input onChange={handleInputChange} placeholder={placeholder} value={valueOfInput}/>
  <CloseIconContainer onClick={() => {setValueOfInput('');setSearchValue('');}}>
    <CloseIcon/>
  </CloseIconContainer>
</Container>
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with losing focus when you click on the `CloseIcon`, causing it to lose visibility. If you link a Codesandbox with the relevant code then I can take a deeper look at it

Comment: I didn't know about that site, thank's! The link is https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-pine-qjxj0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has to do with the `CloseIcon` losing visibility. Once the user clicks on the `CloseIcon`, the `Input` loses focus, causing the icon to disappear, thus preventing it from firing the `onClick` event attached to it.

The reason that wrapping the icon fixes the issue is because the wrapper still retains visibility here - it's not being targeted by CSS. Since the `onClick` event handler is attached to the wrapper, it can be fired and thus your code works as expected.

So the easiest solution is to use the wrapper like you already did. Wrapping `svg` elements inside of `div` tags is also a good practice  in general.

If you can't use a wrapper for whatever reason, then either try to come up with an alternative CSS method, or use Javascript to hide and show the icon.

Comment: that's a shame, I'd really like to not have a wrapper, do you have any idea how to do this effect without a wrapper and keeping the visibility: hidden? I searched for function that work when a component gets unmounted but they aparently don't exist

Comment: You could place `onFocus` and `onBlur` event handlers on your `Input` component and control the state of showing/hiding your icon that way. However, you'll have to write a lot more code than wrapping a simple `div` tag around your icon